# WPF MessageBox style not getting set

Tags: .net, wpf, wpf-controls, themes

I am trying to use a wpf theme using ResourceDictonary. It gets applied on TabControl, Buttons, TextInput and other controls except MessageBox. Here is how I applied the theme.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/PresentationFramework.Aero;component/themes/aero.normalcolor.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

I also uncommented dependencyAssembly in app.manifest file, but it doesn't seem to work for me. I don't want to use Extended WPF Toolkit. Any suggestions on how I can apply the theme on MessageBox control.

IDE: Visual Studio 2010, Windows 7

Comment: I hope, it may help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289328/wpf-messagebox-window-style

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried that. MessageBox takes the style from OS, so even if I change it from Aero to Royale or luna, it still shows Aero theme for MessageBox. When I set my system for "Best Performance", all the glossy effect will go and MessageBox effects are also gone.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369689/wpf-messagebox-buttons-arent-os-themed .... Use a modified app.manifest, then try running outside of VisualStudio, or disabling the hosting process, so that the manifest is honoured