# WPF Open FIle Dialog theme

Tags: wpf, dialog, themes, openfiledialog

I'm using `Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog` in my WPF application for selecting file:

```
var dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog
{
    Title = "Select configuration",
    DefaultExt = ".xml",
    Filter = "XML-file (.xml)|*.xml",
    CheckFileExists = true
};

if (dlg.ShowDialog() == true)
{
//...
}
```

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969773.aspx#Common_Dialogs) screenshots on Windows 7 dialog must have modern style, but I'm getting the old one:

[image]

Adding manifest like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289328/wpf-messagebox-window-style) question doesn't works. How to get dialogs like in MSDN shown?

**EDIT:**

First of all, I'm interested in "native" solution, not using third-party components.

Comment: I know the comment "works on my machine" isn't usually helpful, but I pasted your code into a newly created project on my Windows 7 box.  The correct dialog is displayed. Is there anything unusual about your machine settings?

Comment: @Cameron Peters, Windows 7 x64. WPF project for .Net Framework 3.5. What application have you created (for .Net 3.5 or 4.0)?

Comment: Windows 7 Ultimate, 32 bit.  WPF project for .Net Framework 4.0.

Comment: when I switch the target to .Net 3.5, I get the old style dialog.  Are you able to target 4.0, or are you required to stick with 3.5?

Comment: @Cameron Peters, I can switch. Probably with .NET 4.0 `OpenFileDialog` executes new code with modern dialogs. Thanks for helping. Add this to your answer, I will mark it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will get the correct dialog if you switch your target to the .Net 4.0 full or client profile.

Some of the modern common dialogs are only available in WPF if you use the [Windows 7 Code Pack](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack), but the new style open dialog is available when you target .Net 4.0.

Comment: its a possible way, but how Microsoft got modern dialogs with their code snippet in MSDN? Or its a fake? By the way, most of features of Windows 7 Code Pack was added in .Net Framework 4.

Comment: @archer.  I'm guessing now, but try adding a manifest to your application.  Perhaps that impacts the choice of which set of common dialogs to use... sorry couldn't find a good link on the topic in the 10 seconds I have to respond before heading home for the weekend...