# Windows Classic-style button in WPF MessageBox!

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, button, messagebox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WPF MessageBox window style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289328/wpf-messagebox-window-style)

Why does WPF have the Windows Classic type buttons in its MessageBox's?

[image]

Is there a way to trick WPF into thinking this is the 21st century? Not 1945...

Comment: Answered here: [WPF MessageBox window style](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289328/wpf-messagebox-window-style)