# Does anyone know how to get the WPF MessageBox to look better (like the Windows Forms equivelant)?

Tags: .net, wpf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WPF MessageBox window style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289328/wpf-messagebox-window-style)

For some reason the `MessageBox` that comes with WPF has visual styles disabled and I can't find a way to turne them on, in Windows Forms it was simply a matter of calling `Application.EnableVisualStyles()` at the start of your program.

To get an idea of what I'm talking about, here are the two examples:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Application.EnableVisualStyles();
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(
    "Windows Forms Dialog",
    "Message Box Test",
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.OK,
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
```

[image: Windows Forms MessageBox]

```
System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(
    "WPF Dialog",
    "Message Box Test",
    System.Windows.MessageBoxButton.OK,
    System.Windows.MessageBoxImage.Asterisk);
```

[image: WPF MessageBox]

Calling `System.Windows.Forms.Application.EnableVisualStyles()` has no affect for WPF.

The [Extended WPF Toolkit](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MessageBox&referringTitle=Home) has a nice themable implementation, but I'm looking for a way to create message boxes that match the operating system that the user is running on. The EWPFT implementation is fantastic if you want the same style on every operating system.

Comment: I must apologise, yes, this is a duplicate, not sure why I didn't see it in the search result.

Comment: No problem.  I've run into this problem before myself so I knew to search for "wpf messagebox manifest".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use MessageBox anymore, P/Invoke [TaskDialogIndirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760544%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead - it looks nicer than both of those, and has more options (for example, having arbitrary button text)

Comment: Thanks Paul, looks like a workable solution to also provide extra functionality.

Comment: @David Stop using XP. Pretty please?

Comment: @paul yeah I've stopped but my clients plug on with it! If you want to sell software then you have to support xp.

Comment: @Paul, it's not as bad as "it doesn't work on IE 6" :)

Comment: @David, you can always wrap the taskdialog in a check for the OS. That is what MS did in the VistaBridge SDK sample: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms756482(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: @erno of course this is what you do. I was just pointing out that it would be needed.