# Why standard buttons displayed flat C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I have a windows-form which runs without any problem and displayed well. But if I run an instance of this windows-form from an XNA project my standard buttons are displayed as flat versions. How can I fix it ?

[image: This is how buttons look like if I open it from XNA-Project]

[image: This is how buttons look like if I run it from its own exe]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add manifest file to.your.project.
Check this question for info how to do it: [WPF MessageBox window style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289328/wpf-messagebox-window-style)

Comment: System.Windows.Forms.Application.EnableVisualStyles(); -> this command solves the problem [i get it from the link you have posted, thank you]