# WPF MessageBox looks unstyled, while WindowsForms MessageBox looks good

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, messagebox

For some reason, the WPF MessageBox looks worse than the one in WindowsForms. The WPF one doesn't have a visual style.

How can the Windows style be applied to the WPF MessageBox?

**WindowsForms**

[image: WindowsForms]

**WPF**

[image: WPF]

Comment: You can change `style of WPF message box`. http://weblogs.asp.net/psheriff/a-wpf-message-box-you-can-style Or http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/619333/All-Purpose-Message-Box-in-WPF

Comment: I want the default Windows one, like in WindowsForms, not something custom drawn.

Comment: Looks like the Windows 7 style is used, even though you're clearly under Windows 8.x. This is a bug in WPF. You should report to connect / create a UserVoice request.

Comment: It's Windows classic style, not even Windows 7. And I don't think creating a bug request will help me right now. Are there any fixes, like some sort of style manifests?

Comment: @bytecode77 You should still report this bug. Otherwise it's never going to get fixed. Looking at the WPF internal code it seems like it's just calling user32.dll internally. I wonder why would the winforms one look any different.

Comment: I managed it using an `app.manifest`. I will answer my question unless nobody else comes up with something else. Still, weird that no one found this bug yet. It's so obvious.

Comment: I dont think you're the only one: This is exactly the same [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289328/wpf-messagebox-window-style)

Comment: @bytecode77: it's a common problem, and the manifest usually does the trick.

Comment: Seems to be the way to go. I wrote an answer to this below. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This issue can be fixed by adding an application manifest (Add -> New Item -> Application Manifest File)

```
    ...
</trustInfo>
<dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity
            type="win32"
            name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
            version="6.0.0.0"
            processorArchitecture="*"
            publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
            language="*" />
    </dependentAssembly>
</dependency>
```

Under **"Project Properties"**, point "Manifest" to the file you just created. This is optional for that the manifest can also just be deployed along with the EXE file.

**Note:** This manifest can be used for any executable, not only WPF, that needs to be "styled".